# What happens when you take the limit with a big-oh error?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

What happens if you have some error in your expression and you wish to take the limit? Does the big-oh go away or are you unable to take a limit at all?

This may seem very obvious as it is likely I am misunderstanding the definition of big-oh?

Answer (score 1):

Check your definitions. Big-Oh and limits should commute:

$\begin{align*}
  \lim_{n \to \infty} (f(n) + O(g(n)))
     = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) + O(\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n))
\end{align*}$

Answer (score 0):

What you understand under $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} O(g(n))$? Set of limits of all members?

If exists $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} g(n)$, then  $O(\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} g(n))=O(1)$, so here are bounded functions. On another hand even if we assume that all members of $O(g(n))$ have limits, then we obtain set of numbers, not bounded functions.

$$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} O(g(n)) \ne O(\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} g(n))$$

Comment: I'm confused, what you've written seems to contradict what vonbrand wrote completely...

Comment: I also am waiting if/when @vonbrand will explain his answer.